# How to put JSON lat/long on the map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have been trying to display the Latitude and the longitude of an JSON API on the map,I have now parse the json values and created a itemized overlay using android book. However the two things are not connected and i'm not sure of how to put the parse lat/long on to the map. Can any one give me a solution

I'm trying to parse the values into array and display them on the map.

How can I achieve this ?

Any solution will be grateful.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   // mapView.setStreetView(true);
   // mapView.isStreetView();
   // mapView.isSatellite();

    JSONArray properties = null;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        properties = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROPERTY);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = 
                            properties.getJSONObject(i);                
            String lat = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
            String longi = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
            System.out.println(lat);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }//getting JSOn values

    Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapmarker); 
    marker.setBounds((int)(-marker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2),
            -marker.getIntrinsicHeight(),
            (int) (marker.getIntrinsicWidth()/2), 
            0);

    InterestingLocations funPlaces = new InterestingLocations(marker);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(funPlaces);

    GeoPoint pt = funPlaces.getCenterPt();
    double latSpan = funPlaces.getLatSpanE6();
    double lonSpan = funPlaces.getLonSpanE6();
    Log.v("Overlays", "Lat span is " + latSpan);
    Log.v("Overlays", "Lon span is " + lonSpan);

    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setCenter(pt);
    mc.zoomToSpan((int)(latSpan*1.5), (int)(lonSpan*1.5));
}



@Override
protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

class InterestingLocations extends ItemizedOverlay {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> locations = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private GeoPoint center = null;
```

I need to replace the below code using array of objects

```
    public InterestingLocations(Drawable marker)
    {
        super(marker);

        // create locations of interest
        GeoPoint Maddox = new 
            GeoPoint((int)(51.513292002080306*1000000),(int)(-0.1420965932139256*1000000));

        GeoPoint WoburnPlace = new 
            GeoPoint((int)(51.52457273349151*1000000),(int)(-0.12765430497584865*1000000));

        GeoPoint Capstansquare = new 
                GeoPoint((int)(51.49858590609855*1000000),(int)(-0.007696115597470304*1000000));

        GeoPoint Devonshire = new 
                GeoPoint((int)(51.52222533547292*1000000),(int)(-0.1440394063396748*1000000));

        GeoPoint Bolsover = new 
                GeoPoint((int)(51.52266783118477*1000000),(int)(-0.14358896505772278*1000000));


        GeoPoint Haymarket = new 
                GeoPoint((int)(51.51000027761305*1000000),(int)(-0.13300746016819762*1000000));


        locations.add(new OverlayItem(Haymarket, 
                "Seven Seas Lagoon", "Seven Seas Lagoon"));

        locations.add(new OverlayItem(Bolsover, 
                "Seven Seas Lagoon", "Seven Seas Lagoon"));

        locations.add(new OverlayItem(Devonshire, 
                "Seven Seas Lagoon", "Seven Seas Lagoon"));

        locations.add(new OverlayItem(Capstansquare, 
                "Seven Seas Lagoon", "Seven Seas Lagoon"));

       locations.add(new OverlayItem(WoburnPlace, 
               "Seven Seas Lagoon", "Seven Seas Lagoon"));

        locations.add(new OverlayItem(Maddox, 
               "Magic Kingdom", "Magic Kingdom"));

        populate();
    }

    //  We added this method to find the middle point of the cluster
    //  Start each edge on its opposite side and move across with each point.
    //  The top of the world is +90, the bottom -90,
    //  the west edge is -180, the east +180
    public GeoPoint getCenterPt() {
        if(center == null) {
            int northEdge = -90000000;   // i.e., -90E6 microdegrees
            int southEdge = 90000000;
            int eastEdge = -180000000;
            int westEdge = 180000000;
            Iterator<OverlayItem> iter = locations.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                GeoPoint pt = iter.next().getPoint();
                if(pt.getLatitudeE6() > northEdge) northEdge = pt.getLatitudeE6();
                if(pt.getLatitudeE6() < southEdge) southEdge = pt.getLatitudeE6();
                if(pt.getLongitudeE6() > eastEdge) eastEdge = pt.getLongitudeE6();
                if(pt.getLongitudeE6() < westEdge) westEdge = pt.getLongitudeE6();
            }
            center = new GeoPoint((int)((northEdge + southEdge)/2),
                    (int)((westEdge + eastEdge)/2));
        }
        return center;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
        // Here is where we can eliminate shadows by setting to false
        super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
    }


    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return locations.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return locations.size();
    }
}
```

I need to achieve something like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349646/Dynamic-JSON-parser

Is this what you are looking for? This will let you parse the JSON, now how to put them on the map, i am unsure, I have only used the bingMaps Rest services. If you are not satisfied with this JSON Parser look around google a bit.

EDIT: Also, why an array over a list? Lists are quite useful especially if you have an unknown number of inputs going into your array. 
List myLatitude = List();
It is a very useful method to the point where I almost never use Arrays while programming web Apps.

ANSWER TO ADDING GEO-POINTS TO MAP:

```
GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(35410000, 139460000);
OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Sekai, konichiwa!", "I'm in Japan!");
```

For more information on how overlay works look at Part 2 under this link:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html
Here is plenty of useful examples on how to use Android maps view. Good luck!

Comment: PLease have a look at the end of the question which is similar to what I need.

Comment: Whether using a list or array is the same to me but my main problem is how can I put the parsed values on to the map?